# PCA for unsupervised feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, unsupervised-learning, pca

If I understood correctly, "using results of PCA to select features" (as recommended in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29572/is-it-possible-to-do-feature-selection-for-unsupervised-machine-learning-problem)) implies visually analysing bi-plots of first two principal components - i.e. the angle between a feature and a principal component.  This approach seems impossible with high number of features. Is there a way to interpret the loadings of principal components for automatic feature selection?